# Zip command on Linux - zip warning: name not matched

Tags: java, linux, maven, zip, cicd

I am running a BitBucket pipeline which tries to zip some archives, but gets an error.

**Working Example**

I have one application for which it works perfectly:

```
zip powwow.zip appspec.yml target/pow-wow-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar scripts/*
  adding: appspec.yml (deflated 26%)
  adding: target/pow-wow-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar (deflated 9%)
  adding: scripts/deploy.sh (deflated 37%)
  adding: scripts/powwow-deploy-old.sh (deflated 37%)
  adding: scripts/powwow-deploy.sh (deflated 53%)
```

Folder structure:

```
- | pom.xml
  | appspec.yml
  | scrips | powwow-deploy.sh
  | target | pow-wow-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

All the files are zipped up into the `powwow.zip` archive as expected.

**Non Working Example**

Now I have another application which needs to to the same thing. The folder structure is slightly different, because the EAR file is in a different folder (`corporateEAR` ).

```
zip -r corpapp.zip appspec.yml corporateEAR/target/cEAR-3.10.ear scripts/*
    zip warning: name not matched: corporateEAR/target/cEAR-3.10.ear
  adding: appspec.yml (deflated 25%)
  adding: scripts/corpapp-deploy.sh (deflated 42%)
```

Do you know why it cannot match on the `corporateEAR/target/cEAR-3.10.ear`?

Folder structure:

```
- | pom.xml
  | appspec.yml
  | scrips | corpapp-deploy.sh
  | corporateEAR | target | cEAR-3.10.ear
```

[image]

More info:

If I run this command from the directory on my local machine it works, i.e. it creates the zip archive as expected. However if this command is run from the Bitbucket pipeline, it gets the above warning that it cannot match the ear file.

```
zip -r corpapp.zip appspec.yml corporateEAR/target/cEAR-3.10.ear scripts/*
```

Comment: Why using external zip command instead of using maven-assembly-plugin to create the resulting archive? Also naming is a bit strange because usually all artifacts are lower case...

Comment: Hi khmarbaise, thanks for the reply.  It is an existing old application, so the naming convention was done ages ago, I am just working with what I have. I am creating a zip archive of all the artefacts that need to be copied to the deployment server via a S3 bucket, so it is putting it in one zip archive to upload it.

Comment: If the ear root directory hasn't moved position (correct me if I'm wrong about that) then it might be something else. e.g. *`scripts/*`*. The glob is redundant as the recursion flag is set and the glob might cause shell-related problems, so try getting rid of it (i.e. just `scripts`)

Comment: Does not change a thing you can do that via maven-assembly-plugin... no need for external scripts etc.